# Android GridLayout match_parent not centered itself

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am using this guy's codes for grid layout [Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677). But if I try to modify code to match parent

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

it looks like this,

[image]

how can fix it. in linear layout may be I would chang layout weight. but in grid layout I dont know what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Grid layout fills parent and basically there's no room for manoeuvre.